# Cleaning up after a failed BSD Ports Make Install Attempt?

Tags: compilation, makefile, bsd, openbsd, vax

I am trying to clean up after failed installs from `ports` of Emacs 21 and Emacs 23 as well as Git. I was trying to install Emacs and Git on an OpenBSD v5.2 install on a DEC VaxStation 4000 model 90. It has a staggering 32 megs of RAM and a 2.1 gig hard drive, very high end for 1991 but all this now seems puny; so yes every last megabyte of hard drive space does matter on this hard drive which is now already 72% full.

My attempts at the installs using `make install` within the appropriate directory of the `/usr/ports` tree have failed. I did run `make clean` after each failed compilation and have also checked `/tmp` and it is largely empty. OpenBSD seems to also flush `/tmp` with each reboot. The hard drive capacity does however seem to shrink with each failed program compilation so I am probably accumulating some programs or tarballs or cruft with each attempted installation.

The programs in question are not available as binary packages for the VAX architecture.

How do I clean up after failed ports compilations in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Run `rm -rf /usr/ports/pobj`.

Check also the directory `packages` within `/usr/ports`.